# Having troubling aligning photo in center in css

Tags: html, css

I am a new to HTML and am learning the language, but when I tried to create this website the top photo will not align in the center. I have tried vertical-align and padding, but with zero luck. Putting my code down below.Thanks for the replies!

```css
.hudson {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 60px;
  top: 105px;
  font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.threeD {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 3px 0 #bbb, 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9, 0 5px 0 #aaa, 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
.p1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
.p2 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
.p3 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
.coding {
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.paracolor {
  color: skyblue;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Orbitron;
  text-align: center;
}
#icons {
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
#icons i {
  color: white;
}
body {
  background-image: url(PICTURES1/mountains4.jpeg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<img class="coding animated fadeInDown" src="PICTURES1/coding.png" style="max-width:125px;max-height:125px;">
<h2 class="hudson threeD animated fadeInDown">Hudson Reamer</h2>
<p class="paracolor p1 animated fadeInRightBig">blah blah blah</p>
<p class="paracolor p2 animated fadeInLeftBig">blah blah blah</p>
<p class="paracolor p3 animated fadeInRightBig">blah blah blah</p>
<div id="icons">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hreamer/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-4x"></i></a>
  <a href="mailto:reamer.hudson@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-4x"></i></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%40hreamer&src=typd&lang=en"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: `align-items` is used for Flexbox items; see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Thanks for the comment though! Sorry for not putting that in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can center a standalone-element by using a left- and right-margin value `auto`. Since the image is an inline element, you also have to use `display: block;` on it to get this to work. And the element needs a width:

```css
.hudson {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 60px;
  top: 105px;
  font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.threeD {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 3px 0 #bbb, 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9, 0 5px 0 #aaa, 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
.p1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
.p2 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
.p3 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
.coding {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width:125px;
  max-height:125px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.paracolor {
  color: skyblue;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Orbitron;
  text-align: center;
}
#icons {
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
#icons i {
  color: white;
}
body {
  background-image: url(PICTURES1/mountains4.jpeg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<img class="coding animated fadeInDown" src="PICTURES1/coding.png">
<h2 class="hudson threeD animated fadeInDown">Hudson Reamer</h2>
<p class="paracolor p1 animated fadeInRightBig">blah blah blah</p>
<p class="paracolor p2 animated fadeInLeftBig">blah blah blah</p>
<p class="paracolor p3 animated fadeInRightBig">blah blah blah</p>
<div id="icons">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hreamer/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-4x"></i></a>
  <a href="mailto:reamer.hudson@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-4x"></i></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%40hreamer&src=typd&lang=en"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've not searched enough as a junior developer. There are number of ways you can do this if you would have google it.

Just add

> padding: 0 0 0 47%;

in your img tag style.

```
<img class="coding animated fadeInDown" src="PICTURES1/coding.png" style="padding: 0 0 0 47%; max-width:125px;max-height:125px;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment and feedback! Helped me.